# Empty window left in Edge when a document retrieved from a document storage site opens within another application

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

We have just changed our default browser from IE11 to Edge and when retrieving documents from our document storage system it now leaves an empty window when it goes off to another application to open the document.
With IE it just opened the document in the window we created but this is not happening with Edge.

I am using window.open to create the window below is the script that creates it

```
window.open'URLofDocumentSystem?jsessionid=sId&operation=RETRIEVEITEM&ID=docID','Docviewer',
    'location=0, status=0, toolbar=0, resizable=1, width=1024, height=768, scrollbars=1')
```

The problem is that I don't know how the document will open until I have retrieved it from the external system, the system users are getting annoyed with the empty window that is being left on the screen and I was wondering how I can remove it.
I have tried adding a window.close statement after the window.open however by this point control has passed over to whichever application is opening the document - there are about 12 different types of documents returned from the document system.
If the default application for the returned object is Edge, it works correctly and opens the document within the window created however I can't change this for all document types that are returned

Is there anyway I can force Edge to open the document within the window I create? or is there another way for me to open the URL without it leaving the blank window? or is there a way for me to force the window shut if the document is opened in another application?

Comment: Can you try opening it in an iframe?

Comment: I think you can't force the document to be opened in Edge as users can choose to use which application to open the document. If the document is opened in other applications, the `window.open` window must be blank. You can try CherryDT's suggestion to open it in an iframe as a workaround.

Comment: @CherryDT Thanks for the help here, I tried to create an iFrame but it no longer seemed to open the document when I did so. I am going to go back to the users and tell them that are going to have to accept that they will need to close the blank window when using Edge